# HTML - Putting Two Different Tables Beside Each Other

Tags: html

I want to make these two tables to be placed beside each other. I tried using `div` but unable to put them side by side. So I tried using `style="display: inline-block`, yet it doesn't work. Need help on this.

```html
<form id="checkbox1" method="get" align="left">
  <table style="width:30%" align="left" style="display: inline-block;">

    <input type="checkbox" value="select" align="center" id="check1"> Calculate The Number of Head Count When Days Are Fixed<br>

    <tr>
      <td>Number of Days</td>
      <td class="left"><input type="text" id="numDays" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Head Count</td>
      <td class="left"><input type="text" name="hc" id="hc" /> Per Shift</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>


<form id="checkbox2" method="get" align="left">
  <table style="width:30%" align="left" style="display: inline-block;">

    <input type="checkbox" value="select" align="center" id="check2"> Calculate The Number of Days When Head Counts Are Fixed<br>
    <tr>
      <td>Number of Head Count</td>
      <td class="left"><input type="text" id="numHeadC" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Number of Days</td>
      <td class="left"><input type="text" name="days" id="days" /> Days</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: @Quentin Thanks a lot for your feedback. Will try to improve my codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables aren't siblings. You need to style the **forms** so they are side by side.

Set `display: inline-block` on the form elements.

You should also fix the errors that [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) would pick up.

Answer (score -2):

```
form{
width: 50%;
float: left;
padding: 0 15px;
}
```